# Improve monoexponential curve fitting in the initial portion

Tags: optimization, fitting, curve-fitting

I've calculated the Tissue Volume and Tissue Mass from a Computed Tomography image of the lung of a given patient.

The y-axis of the attached figure is Volume as a percentage of the total lung capacity, so it goes from 0 to 100%. The x-axis is the patient's lung cumulative Mass in grams, so it goes from 0 (or close to  0) to 475g (total lung mass). I would like to investigate the behavior of this curve in some patients with different lung diseases. Some of these diseases destroy the lung and consequently air volume will increase and mass content will reduce. My idea was to fit the Volume x Mass curve with a monoexponential equation (Equation is shown below) and use the K3 ("Time constant") coefficient to quantify how fast is the curve response. Depending on the severity of the disease, the curve can increase faster, and as a consequence, it will have a smaller K3 compared with a healthy subject.

The problem is: the monoexponential seems to fit this type of curve poorly, mostly in the beginning portion of the curve, in special between 0-100 grams. 
Some persons told me to use weighted regression to overcome this limitation. But I am not familiar with this technique. Can anyone help me to implement this regression in Python, R or Matlab?  Here is the [link](https://github.com/rhenanbartels/fit-example) of a GitHub repository with the code and an example of the Volume x Mass curve and its fitted curve.

Apart from the weighted regression, does anyone knows any other equation that could fit the Volume x Mass curve with better results and still give me the "Time/Mass constant" or some sort of coefficient that tells me how fast is the curve response? Maybe some sort of biexponential equation.

The monoexponential Equation that I used:
 $$V_{(\%)} = K1 + K2*e^{(-M/K3)}$$

where K1, K2, and K3 are the coefficients to be estimated and M is the lung tissue mass;

At the picture below, the BLUE line is the Observed and the RED is Predicted.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: I see that the blue line is above the red line at X = 50, but this is reversed at X = 225. From this characteristic, the plot of regression error versus X should have a sort of wave shape up and down around an error value of zero. Since the equation in your post does not have such a wave shape, there appears to be some other component in the data that does not fit this equation. In my understanding, you must either use weighted fitting to force the curve as you describe - giving a worse fit elsewhere - or use some modification to the posted equation.

Comment: 1. Please clarify which curve is which. $\ $2. If you only care about fit in the left part, throw out the data to the right, so it won't drag the fit toward it. If you don't want to throw it out completely, you could do a weighted regression where you reduce the weight away from the area of interest. A more satisfying alternative could be to consider that perhaps some other function might fit the data better at both ends. Are other functions used in this application area?

Comment: Sorry @JamesPhillips, I've just edited the Question and added a link to GitHub with the code and a sample data.  Thanks for the tip in Weighted fitting. I will take a look at some examples

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for your comment. I am still exploring the idea of fitting this type of curve. If you have any suggestion about which equation to use I will be happy to learn it

Comment: One thinhg that is nice about the Monoexponential equation that I used is the K3 coefficient. It tells me how fast the is the curve response, which is important to know.

Comment: I performed an equation search on 600+ nonlinear and 1800+ linear equations, and could not completely  fit the "wave component" portion of the data. One possibility is to split the data set into two overlapping segments and fit those separately, the overlap giving a smoother transition between the two regions of the combined model. Other than that, weighted fitting seems to be the only option that I see here. I also tried third and fourth order splines and in my fitting, they also stink.

Comment: The observed (blue) curve looks like it as an asymptote at zero, which can't be fit with an exponential. Can you explain the nature of this data?

Comment: I see that you have edited the question to add a great level of detail, explaining exactly what you are doing and the exact nature of your question - yet this question is still on hold as unclear. Because of the on hold status I am unable to answer with Python code for both weighted regression on your data and a split model, which I can provide. Would it be OK if I add such example code to your linked github project?

Comment: Hi @JamesPhillips, I will be very glad if you fork the repository and add the example. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: OK, will do - no problem.

Comment: Done. You should have a new pull request on the repository.

Comment: Hi @JamesPhillips, thank you very much for your PR. You did a great job with a detailed code. I will spend this week studying your script and learning from it. If you feel like, you could also post your answer here, so other people can access it and eventually upvote.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but only an explanation about the difficulty that you mentioned :

> The problem is: the monoexponential seems to fit this type of curve poorly, mostly in the beginning portion of the curve, in special between 0-100 grams. Some persons told me to use weighted regression to overcome this limitation.

If the observed curve (blue) is drawn as $V^2$ as a function of $M$ (curve below) one can see that it becomes quite linear in the beginning portion of the curve:

[image]

This means that, for lowest $M$ values, the function behaves roughly as:
$$V\simeq C\,\sqrt{M}\tag 1$$
where $C$ is a constant.

Of course this oversimplified relationship is not valid for $M$ large.

Now, consider the supposed relationship :
$$V_{(\%)} = K_1 + K_2*e^{(-M/K_3)}$$

For low values of $M$ the main term of series expansion is :
$$V\simeq K_1 + K_2*(1-\frac{M}{K_3})$$
And $V(0)=0$ implies $K_2=-K_1$
$$V\simeq K_1 - K_1*(1-\frac{M}{K_3})$$
$$V\simeq\frac{K_1}{K_3}M \tag 2$$
Comparing Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ shows that the supposed  monoexponential Equation behaves like $M$ while the observed phenomena behaves like $\sqrt{M}$.

This appears the cause of discrepancy that you observe: The monoexponential Equation is not a correct equation to model the phenomena on the low range of $M$.

So, I doubt that a weighted regression will solve the problem. Of course, the fitting can be improved on the low range of $M$ but the fitting will become bad for the large values of $M$.

I think that the global improvement cannot come from playing around with the regression itself, but should come from a more advanced study of the phenomena and a better mathematical model than the simple monoexponential Equation.

For example with the combination of the function $a\:\sqrt{M}$ and a function of logistic kind :

[image]

Note that the numerical values of the parameters obtained from non-linear regression are probably not accurate because the data isn't the correct data but comes from scanning the figure published in the question. Scanning a figure is not an accurate method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found an answer, but for me the model is not correct with the problem. Thus, if the expected behavior of the problem is essentially exponential, it appears to be multiexponential. We have some processing algorithms using the Tikhonov regularization that can be applied to fit a multi-exponential recovery or decay curve. Very nice the proposal.